# Ubuntu hangs on ryzen 5 1600 processor

Tags: amd-ryzen

I bought a computer of the following assembly:

- AMD Ryzen 5 1600
- 16 GB DDR4-2666
- NVIDIA GeForce GT 710

when installing versions of ubuntu 18.4.3, 18.4.4, 20.4, hangs are observed, a way out of which is possible only with the computer turned off.

Hangs can occur when the system boots up or a few minutes after the start.

On windows 10 there is no such problem.

Currently installed ubuntu 18.4.4

Tell me, plz, how to get rid of freezes?